# Trouble with Cookie persistence in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-plugins

I am setting my cookie when user click a certain link on my web page. I am using jQuery [Cookie plugin developed by Klaus Hartl](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie). To set the cookie value I do the following:

```
 $.cookie("lanVal", "tv", {expires: 3});
```

But when testing the cookie functionality, I see that IE does not save the cookie properly. All other browsers retain the value and the cookie value is load next time the page is opened. In IE, I get null when I open the page. What extra settings am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the path?  eg.

```
$.cookie("lanVal", "tv", {path: '/', expires: 3});
```

Comment: yes.. I tried the path. also the domain.. with the value 'localhost' as I am running it on my PC...